# Php unit test takes long time and then times out in Gitlab

Tags: php, laravel, docker, phpunit, gitlab-ci

We are using below command to run php unit tests.  It runs in less than 10 minutes on the local machine but it runs for 4-6 hours in Gitlab job(using php linux docker image) and then it times out:

```
      curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php 
      alias composer='php composer.phar'
      cd src/ && php ../composer.phar install
      time vendor/bin/phpunit \
        --process-isolation \
        --log-junit build/phpunit.xml \
        --coverage-text \
        --coverage-clover build/coverage.xml \
        --colors=never \
          tests
```

It is also not generating `build/coverage.xml` file.  Can someone please help as to which php config changes/commands I need to use.

Comment: I think you can compare system specifications between your local PC and the CI/CD runner. However, I believe that running tests locally for about 10 minutes is too long. Either your application is too large, or you're writing tests inefficiently. This could be because you're writing too many integration tests instead of unit tests. There is an approach called pyramid testing that you can reference.